rsyslog ompgsql cannot connect to server while psql can
I have the following problem with Ubuntu 24.04.1:

the rsyslog service is configured to log to PostgreSQL using the ompgsql module
when starting rsyslog service, the ompgsql module complains with ompgsql.c: pgsql, DBError(silent): db error (1): no connection to the server
when connecting using psql, everything works as expected.

Here is my conf file:
/etc/rsyslog.d/20-pgsql.conf
module (load="ompgsql")
*.* action(type="ompgsql" server="rsyslog-postgres" db="rsyslog" uid="rsyslog" pwd="rsyslog")

Log output is:
1703.733789103:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: initPgSQL: host=rsyslog-postgres port=5432 dbname=rsyslog uid=rsyslog
1703.734128454:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: initPgSQL: ssl status: 0
1703.734158855:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: writePgSQL: select 'a' as a
1703.734186486:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: postgres query execution failed: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR
1703.734205567:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: initPgSQL: host=rsyslog-postgres port=5432 dbname=rsyslog uid=rsyslog
1703.734502896:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: initPgSQL: ssl status: 0
1703.734530467:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: postgres query execution failed: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR
1703.734566269:main Q:Reg/w0  : ompgsql.c: pgsql, DBError(silent): db error (1): no connection to the server

psql-command that works is:
export PGPASSWORD=rsyslog
psql -h rsyslog-postgres -U rsyslog rsyslog

As said, rsyslog cannot connect, while the psql command can. I am but puzzled how this can be.

I faced the same problem: rsyslog and postgresql running on the same virtual ubuntu server, rsyslog failing to connect to postgres db. Tried lots of things to no avail. Then I moved rsyslog to another virtual server and it worked like magic - no problem in connecting to postgres.

*.* action(type="ompgsql" server="rsyslog-postgres" db="rsyslog" uid="rsyslog" pwd="rsyslog")

Tells rsyslog to use tcp to connect postgres, so 'rsyslog-postgres' then needs to be as DNS hostname on the rsyslog server, compared to if rsyslog was told to use the postmaster's UNIX socket, what happends if postgres is on the same host as rsyslog
but you change the connection string to this:
*.* action(type="ompgsql" db="rsyslog" uid="rsyslog" pwd="rsyslog")

This could run afoul of access controls in postgres.
